# Adobe premier cs6 file import failure

Tags: adobe-premiere

I created a premier cs6 project few months ago. I have re-installed the OS, installed premier cs6 again. But this time it is reporting error in importing same video files.

Video files are in mpg format and they are well running directly.

ERROR : *"There was an error decompressing audio or video."*

**EDIT**:

Somewhere I found that *SysWOW64/quartz.dll* is required to tell OS about mpg files. This file is installed via directx. I am surprised that directx was already installed but the file was missing. And when I installed same OS on my different machine quartz.dll was there.

Well!! I copied the dll to my this machine and registered it. Still the problem persist. I also have installed K-lite codec pack and Media info. But :(

As an alternative solution, I linked mp4 files in my premier project. But they don't run smooth in adobe which makes video editing impossible.

Please help me to run mpg files in adobe premier.

Comment: It can be codec problem. Try installing codecs, such as K-Lite Codec pack. And tell us if it worked :)

Comment: It must be because it is able to import mp4 files. But I have installed K-lite Codec pack, Media info. Nothing works. And I am able to run mpg files directly.

Comment: it seems that [quartz.dll](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/quartz-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm) is missing. But when I check DirextX version, it says it is installed and it is v11. :(

Comment: Have you downloaded quartz.dll and placed it on program's folder?

Comment: Well! there was some problem with OS installation I guess. So I took it from my another machine. Now I became able to install K-Lite latest version. And in result, I am able to play mpg files directly. Still premier is giving the same problem. I have also installed AdobeMediaEncoderTrial_64-6.0.3. But nothing worked.

Comment: Have you REGISTERED (not replace) quartz.dll? If you don't know how to do it (or what is it), tell me to tell you :)

Comment: yup, I forgot to registered it. lemme try and then update here again. thanks

Comment: is it working now?